# Lazy way to check if all generated elements are equal

Tags: python, generator

Given an iterator that yields comparable values, what would be the lazy way to check if all results are equal. That is, fail as soon as possible, without consuming the whole generator. So `len(set(g))==1` won't work.

I'm looking for a simple expression / combination of library functions. No `def`s.

Comment: It seems to me like you'll have to "look at" each element of the generator at some point, unless generators have some crazy underlying implementation I don't know about...

Comment: Here's a hint: "all elements are equal" == "all elements are the same as the first one".

Comment: (I meant for the specific case when all of the elements are equal.)

Comment: should this belong to http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Expression as given by @unutbu

```
all(y == first for first in gen for y in gen)
```

Test/demo:

```
>>> def test(*args):
...     for a in args:
...         print a,
...         yield a
... 
>>> g = test(1,1,1,1,1,1,1)
>>> print all(a == x for a in g for x in g)
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 True
>>> g = test(1,1,1,2,1,1,1)
>>> print all(a == x for a in g for x in g)
1 1 1 2 False
```

Failed early, as required.

Comment: I needed to see `list((y,first) for first in gen for y in gen)` to convince myself this actually worked - very very neat.

Comment: This is O(N^2) where it should be O(N)... Your `first` variable takes every value in the sequence - you're checking every value is equal to every other value.

Comment: @Eric I think you are wrong because generator can be looped once so how it can be O(N^2) ?

Comment: Oh, I think I'm muddling iterators and iterables. Clever!

Answer (score 7):

How about:

```
first = next(gen)
if all(x==first for x in gen):
    print "They're all the same!"
```

(Rob Wouters described this algorithm in a comment, I just put it into Python)

As F.J spotted, this will fail on an empty iterator, and it assumes you've already got an *iterator*, not just an *iterable*. His answer addresses both points.

Comment: nice work ... doesnt have the same restriction of a known length as mine (Deleted since this is much better)

Comment: but is it an expression? as op asked?

Comment: @AnuragUniyal: It's not. I don't see any neat way of doing it as an expression. It might be possible by ugly hacking with lambdas, but... *readability counts*.

Comment: @AnuragUniyal: Joke: `any(all(x == first for x in gen) for first in [next(gen)])`

Comment: @ThomasK otherwise it is trivial

Comment: For practical purposes, trivial code is a good thing. Coding within arbitrary restrictions can be fun too, but there's a separate board for that: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @AnuragUniyal, the question includes "combination of library functions". This qualifies.

Comment: @ThomasK so may be this question be moved, as op specifically expected code golf, by saying only expression, no defs

Comment: I think you're interpreting the OP a little too literally, Anurag. As I understand it, he's just saying he wants something short and pythonic rather than a clunky function requiring a def. I don't think he *literally* wants us to solve his problem using strictly a single expression.

Comment: @AnuragUniyal: My reading is that the OP wants the best way to do this in the real world, not a code golf exercise. He/she may have been using the term 'expression' more loosely.

Comment: @AnuragUniyal: or `all(y == first for first in gen for y in gen)`. (still joking)

Answer (score 2):

```
def all_equal(iterable):
    itr = iter(iterable)
    try:
        first = next(itr)
    except StopIteration:
        return True
    else:
        return all(item == first for item in itr)
```

- Returns `True` for empty iterables
- Works for any iterable, not just generators

Comment: +1, although while the OP's requirement seems very silly to me, "No defs" was given..

Answer (score 1):

```
from itertools import *

if all(a == b for a, b in izip(gen, islice(gen, 1, None))):
    print "They're all the same!"
```

Although that wouldn't work for iterators.

```
gen1, gen2 = tee(gen)
next(gen1, None)
if all(a == b for a, b in izip(gen1, gen2)):
    print "They're all the same!"
```

Or as a "single expression":

```
if (lambda g, h: all(a == b for a, b in izip(g, islice(h, 1, None))))(*tee(gen)):
    print "They're all the same!"
```

Comment: Thanks! I considered something like this, but the accepted solution looks simpler (given that my question is explicitly about iterators).